# Parsing html with rails and nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I need to parse HTML using Rails and Nokogiri. Here is the HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div id="mama">
    <div class="test1">text</div>
    <div class="test2">text2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="mama">
    <div class="test1">text</div>
    <div class="test2">text2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="mama">
    <div class="test1">text</div>
    <div class="test2">text2</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

How I should form loop question? I've tried so many times but still getting an error or bad results...
...

```
doc.xpath('//div[@id='mama']/?or what?').each do |node|
  parse_file.puts text1 
  parse_file.puts text2
  parse_file.puts text1 
  parse_file.puts \n
end
```

Result should be like

```
text from first mama
text2 from first mama
text from first mama

text from second mama
and so on...
```

Comment: first, you don't use id's multiple times. if you're going to do that, use classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that the HTML you posted is syntactically invalid: it is illegal to have more than one element with the same `id` attribute value. *If* you have control over your HTML, you should fix this problem.

Using that same (invalid) HTML, however, Nokogiri still has no trouble:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(my_html)

doc.css('#mama').each_with_index do |div,i|
  puts "#{div.at_css('.test1').text} from mama ##{i}"
  puts "#{div.at_css('.test2').text} from mama ##{i}"
end

#=> text from mama #0
#=> text2 from mama #0
#=> text from mama #1
#=> text2 from mama #1
#=> text from mama #2
#=> text2 from mama #2
```

If you wanted to use XPath directly (as Nokogiri does behind the scenes for the CSS) you would do this:

```
doc.xpath("//div[@id='mama']").each_with_index do |div,i|
  puts "#{div.at_xpath("./*[@class='test1']").text} from mama ##{i}"
  puts "#{div.at_xpath("./*[@class='test2']").text} from mama ##{i}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, your apostrophes/quotes are off. They should be...

```
doc.xpath('//div[@id="mama"]/?or what?')
```